# make use of the section title for paragraph disambiguation

Tags: nlp, text-extraction, information-extraction

I'm trying to find any idea on how to use section title information to acquire more knowledge or to clarify the content of the paragraph that comes after this title.

For example :

`SECTION TITLE :` Data we collect:

`Paragraph :` Your name , last name , phone number and email are data that can be used to enrich our ads recommendation systems and to be able to provide a better user experience while using our service.

In an ideal situation we can have :
`SECTION TITLE:` Information we collect

`PARAGRAPH` We collect your data such as name, last name, and telephone number to enhance user experience.

we can see in the latter example that the title information in present also in the paragraph. But this is not the case for the first example.

The idea is to be able to capture that the following text is "data to be collected" information extracted from the section title, a piece of information that we omitted in its corresponding paragraph.

Any thoughts ?

Comment: Your target is not clear. Please provide an example of the desired output and show what you tried to do.

Comment: the target is how to use section title as extra information when this is being omitted in the paragraph. The target even for me is not that clear but this is the issue and I was willing this can be a discussion more than a question that needs a certain answer.